# Starting a nomenclatur group on a new page using nomencl

Tags: nomenclature, nomencl

I have two nomenclature groups. Is it possible to force one to start on a new page? I've also reduced the line spacing, but it'd be nice if I could keep the spaceing between the group name and the headers.

Here is my (very scrappy and pasted together from several sources in tex.stackechange) code

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{nomencl, ragged2e, etoolbox, mathtools}
\usepackage{xargs}

\makenomenclature
\DeclarePairedDelimiter{\abs}{\lvert}{\rvert}
\newcommand{\units}[1]{\makebox[4em]{#1\hfill}\ignorespaces}

\newcommand{\nomsubtitle}[1]{\item[\large\bfseries #1]}
\renewcommand\nomgroup[1]{\def\nomtemp{\csname nomstart#1\endcsname}\nomtemp}

\newcommand{\nomstartF}{\nomsubtitle{Formelzeichen}%
\item[\bfseries Symbol]%
\nomdescr{\textbf{Description}}\units{\textbf{Unit}}}

\newcommand{\nomstartA}{\nomsubtitle{Acronyms}%
\item[\bfseries Acronym]\textbf{Description}}


\renewcommand*{\nompreamble}{\markboth{\nomname}{\nomname}}

\newcommand{\nomdescr}[1]{\parbox[t]{10cm}{\RaggedRight #1}}

\newcommand{\nomtypeA}[3][]{\nomenclature[A#1]{#2}{\nomdescr{#3}}}
\newcommand{\nomwithunits}[4]{\nomenclature[#1]{#2}%
{\nomdescr{#3}\units{#4}}} %neuer Befehl zum Gesamtergebnis der Symbole
\newcommand{\nomtypeF}[4][]{\nomwithunits{F#1}{#2}{#3}{#4}}
\setlength{\nomitemsep}{-\parsep}

\nomtypeA{wirk}{wirkleistungsbezogen}
\nomtypeF{a}{Jahr}{annum}

\begin{document}

\printnomenclature[6em]

\end{document}
```

Edit: added minimal document

Comment: Please add a complete minimal document with the document class, packages etc. needed (MWE/minimal working example).

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone in interested, I added changed the \nomstartf command to

```
\newcommand{\nomstartF}{\newpage\nomsubtitle{Formelzeichen}%
\item[\bfseries Symbol]%
\nomdescr{\textbf{Bezeichnung}}\units{\textbf{Einheit}}%
}
```

which forced a new page. Didn't figure out the spacing between title and headings though

Comment: This is just the change which is needed to force a new page.

Comment: Ok. I was only answering my own question but I'll have a look at changing it

Answer (score 0):

I was dealing with a similar issue, however, I went for a simple but hacking solution.
I just added a `\newpage` in the definition of the last item of the first nom group:
`\nomenclature[A]{\textbf{Acronym}}{Description \newpage}`
The result is, that a new page is inserted before the next group header.